# How to open android app from browser with its own process?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried to open app from html but it opens in browsers task. i just want to open my app from html page with its own task.

Comment: How are you opening your app from HTML? What URL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch your activity using an "intent://" URL and specify Intent flags. For example:

`intent://#Intent;package=my.package.app;component=my.package.app.MainActivity;launchFlags=268435456;end;`

specifies `launchFlags=268435456` which sets `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`